# Persisting domain class instance from a Quartz job

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I'm new to Quartz scheduling and I have grasped the basics. But I'm having trouble persisting data model class instance with Quartz. This is the simplified version of my problem:

```
class PlannedRequestsJob {

static triggers = {
    cron name: 'cronTrigger', startDelay:1000, cronExpression: '0/6 * * * * ?'  
}


def execute(){

    def contactInstance = new Contact()
    contactInstance.realname = 'John Doe'
    contactInstance.save()
    print "Quartz job"
}

}
```

This example prints text ***Quartz job*** every 6 seconds but it doesn't create new domain instance. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help a lot if you show the code of your `Contact` class, but even without this information, I'll bet you a dollar to a dime that one of your validation constraints is failing.

To check who wins the bet, change your code to:

```
def execute(){

    def contactInstance = new Contact()
    contactInstance.realname = 'John Doe'
    if (!contactInstance.save()) {
      println "Save failed due to errors: $contactInstance.errors"
    }

    print "Quartz job"
}
```

If I'm right, you should see a message in the console that explains which constraint fails. You can pay my winnings directly into my bank account - I'll PM you the details.

Comment: So what's your bank account? :) I've considered validation constraints failing but I was foolish enough not do it programmatically so I've overlooked something. Thank you.

Comment: @drago you're welcome - you can send my winnings to your favourite charity instead :)